# Does tremor frequency generally increase as Parkinson's disease progresses?

Tags: neuroscience, pathology, muscles, neurophysiology, synapses

I've been trying to research this question, but most if not all the on-line journals require costly subscription, and the studies that are posted look at tremor frequency with regards to other factors.

My question has to do with the tremor frequency, starting at early onset to later stages of Parkinson's disease - over the course of the disease, and without drug treatment (such as L-dopa), does the tremor frequency generally increase?

Comment: are you looking for frequency of tremor episodes (once a day, once an hour etc) or frequency of tremor as oscillatory motion (1Hz, 0.3Hz etc)?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I'm interested in the frequency of the neuromuscular oscillations.

Comment: The question is still unclear, there are multiple parameters related to tremor. Please, look at this article and decide if you need subsequent changes in the question http://www.mdpi.com/1660-4601/8/5/1478/htm

Comment: Mean frequency  (Cf) most likely expresses what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Frequency of tremor typically remains constant for the person. Levadopa (sinemet) does not change the frequency.

Typically the tremor frequency will be in the range from 3Hz to 7Hz.  There is a common phrase when dealing with PWP (Person With Parkinson's Disease). If you have seen one PWP, you have seen one PWP.

Currently I am part of a study by the Micheal J Fox Foundation using Pebble Watches and Smart phones to monitor PD.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1014720/
Hughes AJ, Daniel SE, Kilford L, Lees AJ (1992) Accuracy of clinical diagnosis of Parkinson’s disease: a clinico-pathological study of 100 cases. J Neurol Neurosurg Psychiatry 55: 181-184.

https://blog.getpebble.com/2014/08/25/mjff-intel-parkinsons/